# Shower head discharges water when not using

Tags: plumbing-fixture

Shower head discharges water periodically during day for a few minutes when shower has not been used in months. Shower only, no tub and all plumbing and fixtures 2 yrs old.

Comment: It's bored. Find something for it to do.

Answer (score 1):

With so many generic cartridges out there, the tolerances are not as exact as they used to be and the seals aren't as tight. You could have a slight, temporary spike in the water pressure that would force water through a not so tight seal and out the shower head. The spike could be from your own home, shutting off a faucet or from the water system into your house.